# How to prevent autovacuum for table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, autovacuum

I have big tables in which I have only inserts and selects, so when autovacuum for this tables is running - system is very slow. I have switch off autovacuum for specific tables:

```
ALTER TABLE ag_event_20141004_20141009  SET (autovacuum_enabled = false, toast.autovacuum_enabled = false);
ALTER TABLE ag_event_20141014_20141019  SET (autovacuum_enabled = false, toast.autovacuum_enabled = false);
```

After this (some time after) I see:

```
select pid, waiting, xact_start, query_start,query from pg_stat_activity order by query_start;

 18092 | f       | 2014-11-04 22:21:05.95512+03  | 2014-11-04 22:21:05.95512+03  | autovacuum: VACUUM public.ag_event_20141004_20141009 (to prevent wraparound)
 19877 | f       | 2014-11-04 22:22:05.889182+03 | 2014-11-04 22:22:05.889182+03 | autovacuum: VACUUM public.ag_event_20141014_20141019 (to prevent wraparound)
```

What shell I do to switch autovacuuming for this tables at all ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key here is:

```
(to prevent wraparound)
```

This means Postgres **must** autovacuum in order to [free up transaction identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND).

You can not entirely disable this type of autovacuum, but you can reduce its frequency by tuning the  `autovacuum_freeze_max_age` and `vacuum_freeze_min_age` parameters.